# SQL query shall count without initals and only count effectitvely changes

Tags: sql, oracle

Given the table:

```
CREATE TABLE blah (CAT, BUSINESS_NR, TIME_A, VERSION, SOME_CODE) AS
SELECT 'ABC',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2009-02-19 00:00:00 UTC',    1,  'OPP' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC',   456,    TIMESTAMP '2009-03-18 00:00:00 UTC',    1,  'ZUM' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC',   444,    TIMESTAMP '2009-03-18 00:00:00 UTC',    1,  'ZUM' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC',   444,    TIMESTAMP '2009-03-18 00:00:00 UTC',    2,  'MUZ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC',   456,    TIMESTAMP '2009-04-18 00:00:00 UTC',    2,  'XXX' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC',   456,    TIMESTAMP '2009-04-18 00:00:00 UTC',    3,  'XXX' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC',   456,    TIMESTAMP '2009-04-18 00:00:00 UTC',    4,  'UIO' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC',   456,    TIMESTAMP '2009-05-18 00:00:00 UTC',    5,  'RQA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DEF',   637,    TIMESTAMP '2018-02-16 00:00:00 UTC',    1,  'FAW' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DEF',   789,    TIMESTAMP '2018-02-17 00:00:00 UTC',    1,  'WER' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SPZ',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2018-02-16 00:00:00 UTC',    1,  'AAA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SPZ',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2018-02-17 00:00:00 UTC',    2,  'BBB' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SPZ',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2018-02-18 00:00:00 UTC',    3,  'AAA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SPZ',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2018-02-19 00:00:00 UTC',    4,  'CCC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SPZ',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2018-02-20 00:00:00 UTC',    5,  'AAA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SPZ',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2018-02-21 00:00:00 UTC',    6,  'DDD' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SPZ',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2018-02-22 00:00:00 UTC',    7,  'DDD' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SPZ',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2018-02-23 00:00:00 UTC',    8,  'DDD' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SPZ',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2018-02-24 00:00:00 UTC',    9,  'EEE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SPZ',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2018-02-25 00:00:00 UTC',    10, 'EEE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SPZ',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2018-02-26 00:00:00 UTC',    11, 'DDD' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SPZ',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2018-02-27 00:00:00 UTC',    12, 'BBB' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SPZ',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2018-02-26 00:00:00 UTC',    13, 'EEE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SPZ',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2018-02-27 00:00:00 UTC',    14, 'EEE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'FLA',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2018-02-16 00:00:00 UTC',    1, 'ABC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'FLA',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2018-03-17 00:00:00 UTC',    2, 'ABC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'FLA',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2018-04-18 00:00:00 UTC',    3, 'ABC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'FLA',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2018-05-18 00:00:00 UTC',    4, 'AAA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI',   248,    TIMESTAMP '2018-02-17 00:00:00 UTC',    1,  'QWE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI',   248,    TIMESTAMP '2019-02-17 00:00:00 UTC',    2,  'PPP' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI',   357,    TIMESTAMP '2020-02-16 00:00:00 UTC',    1,  'FFF' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI',   420,    TIMESTAMP '2020-02-16 00:00:00 UTC',    1,  'QDS' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI',   357,    TIMESTAMP '2020-02-16 00:00:00 UTC',    2,  'GGG' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI',   357,    TIMESTAMP '2020-02-16 00:00:00 UTC',    3,  'LLL' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI',   357,    TIMESTAMP '2020-02-16 00:00:00 UTC',    4,  'LLL' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI',   357,    TIMESTAMP '2020-08-16 00:00:00 UTC',    4,  'FFF' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI',   357,    TIMESTAMP '2020-10-16 00:00:00 UTC',    5,  'ZZZ' FROM DUAL
```

I need a query that gives me a gouped overview by CAT and MONTH how many changes of SOME_CODE for a BUSINESS_NR happened whith some conditions like:

- the first version 1 (and all versions that are equal for SOME_CODE) mustn't be counted
- all SOME_CODE values that are equal and following each other shall be counted as one

With the hints of all super cool inputs of SQL gurus here in stackoverflow I came up now with the following approach:

```
    SELECT cat, moenat, SUM (version_change) AS total_version_changes
    FROM (SELECT cat,
                 TRUNC (TIME_A, 'MON') AS moenat,
                 CASE
                     WHEN    some_code <>
                             LAG (some_code) OVER (PARTITION BY cat ORDER BY version, time_a)
                          OR LAG (some_code) OVER (PARTITION BY cat ORDER BY version, time_a) IS NULL --Needed for version 1
                     THEN
                         1
                     ELSE
                         0
                 END                      AS version_change
            FROM blah where version >1)
GROUP BY cat, moenat
ORDER BY cat, moenat;
```

... which is almost that what I need. But following topic I need to improve:

Problem:
if the version 1 is in the table then this should be treated as INITIAL value and shall not be counted as a change of SOME_CODE. I have build an example of it for CAT=FLA. Initial value is ABC not is not changed till MAY 2018 -> AAA. So expected change code shall be 1 in MAY 2018. With the existing query I get

```
FLA 01.03.2018  1
FLA 01.04.2018  0
FLA 01.05.2018  1
```

which is effectively not want I want because versions 1-3 are initial values. There is only 1 change in MAY 2018 (version 4).

```
FLA',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2018-02-16 00:00:00 UTC',    1, 'ABC' 
FLA',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2018-03-17 00:00:00 UTC',    2, 'ABC' 
FLA',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2018-04-18 00:00:00 UTC',    3, 'ABC' 
FLA',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2018-05-18 00:00:00 UTC',    4, 'AAA'
```

So epected output here shall be:

```
FLA 01.05.2018  1
```

Can someone help me to fix the problem?

Second experimental table:

```
CREATE TABLE blah (CAT, BUSINESS_NR, TIME_A, VERSION, SOME_CODE) AS
SELECT 'FLA',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2018-02-16 00:00:00 UTC',    1, 'ABC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL --0, because initial
SELECT 'FLA',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2018-03-17 00:00:00 UTC',    2, 'ABC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL --0, because still like initial
SELECT 'FLA',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2018-04-18 00:00:00 UTC',    3, 'ABC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL --0, because still like initial
SELECT 'FLA',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2018-05-18 00:00:00 UTC',    4, 'AAA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL --1, valid change, count for MAY 2018

SELECT 'FLA',   555,    TIMESTAMP '2018-05-18 00:00:00 UTC',    1, 'AAA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL --0, because initial 
SELECT 'FLA',   777,    TIMESTAMP '2018-05-18 00:00:00 UTC',    1, 'ZZZ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL --0, because initial
SELECT 'FLA',   777,    TIMESTAMP '2018-05-18 00:00:00 UTC',    2, 'ZZZ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL --0, because still like initial
SELECT 'FLA',   777,    TIMESTAMP '2018-05-18 00:00:00 UTC',    3, 'ZZZ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL --0, because still like initial
SELECT 'FLA',   777,    TIMESTAMP '2018-06-18 00:00:00 UTC',    4, 'ZZZ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL --0, because still like initial
SELECT 'FLA',   777,    TIMESTAMP '2018-07-18 00:00:00 UTC',    5, 'ZZZ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL --0, because still like initial

SELECT 'FLA',   888,    TIMESTAMP '2018-05-18 00:00:00 UTC',    1, 'ZZZ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL --0, because initial
SELECT 'FLA',   888,    TIMESTAMP '2018-05-18 00:00:00 UTC',    2, 'ZZZ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL --0, because still like initial
SELECT 'FLA',   888,    TIMESTAMP '2018-05-18 00:00:00 UTC',    3, 'ABC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL --1, valid change, count for MAY 2018
SELECT 'FLA',   888,    TIMESTAMP '2018-05-18 00:00:00 UTC',    4, 'DEF' FROM DUAL UNION ALL --1, valid change, count for MAY 2018
SELECT 'FLA',   888,    TIMESTAMP '2018-06-18 00:00:00 UTC',    5, 'GHI' FROM DUAL UNION ALL --1, valid change, count in JUNE 2018

SELECT 'FLA',   999,    TIMESTAMP '2018-05-18 00:00:00 UTC',    1, 'GHI' FROM DUAL UNION ALL --0, because initial 
SELECT 'FLA',   999,    TIMESTAMP '2018-06-18 00:00:00 UTC',    2, 'GHI' FROM DUAL UNION ALL --0, because still like initial
SELECT 'FLA',   999,    TIMESTAMP '2018-09-18 00:00:00 UTC',    3, 'ZIP' FROM DUAL DUAL; --1, valid change, count for SEP 2018
```

OUTPUT SHALL BE:

```
FLA MAY 2018: 3
FLA JUN 2018: 1
FLA SEP 2018: 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second clause in the `OR` condition is what was causing the first "change" to be counted. Also, adding the `business_nr` to the partition clause corrected the counts when testing against your second table.

```sql
  SELECT cat, moenat, SUM (version_change) AS total_version_changes
    FROM (SELECT cat,
                 TRUNC (TIME_A, 'MON')    AS moenat,
                 CASE
                     WHEN some_code <>
                          LAG (some_code)
                              OVER (PARTITION BY cat, business_nr ORDER BY version, time_a)
                     THEN
                         1
                     ELSE
                         0
                 END                      AS version_change
            FROM blah)
GROUP BY cat, moenat
  --clause below can be commented/uncommented to hide rows where change did not occur
  --HAVING SUM (version_change) > 0
ORDER BY cat, moenat;
```